# adding pixels to jquery .css() left property

Tags: jquery, css

This is my code:

```
var lef=$(this).css("left");
var top=$(this).css("top");
alert(lef);
$(this).after("<div class='edit cancel' style='position:absolute;top:"+top+";left:"+lef+"'>Cancel</div>");
```

Now the statement `var lef=$(this).css("left") + 150`, doesn't seem to work. I want to get the left property and add 150 pixels to it

How can i do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Here's the easiest way (for the general case):

```js
$(this).css('left', '+=150');
$(this).css('top', '-=100');
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties

> As of jQuery 1.6, `.css()` accepts relative values similar to
>   `.animate()`. Relative values are a string starting with `+=` or `-=`
>   to increment or decrement the current value. For example, if an
>   element's padding-left was 10px, `.css( "padding-left", "+=15" )`
>   would result in a total padding-left of 25px.

---

If you need to do it "manually" (for example, as part of creating a new element):

```js
var left = parseInt($(this).css('left')) + 150;
var top = parseInt($(this).css('top'));

$(this).after('<div style="top: ' + top + 'px; left: ' + left + 'px; position: absolute">Cancel</div>');
```

You need to use `parseInt` because `.css('left')` returns `150px`. You then have to put back the `px` as part of the inline style.

Comment: im sorry, that is not the problem here. That's as , if you perform alert(top) , you'll get an alert with the value of 'top' followed by pixels like : 145px
after you edited the answer, it works. thanks a lot :)

Comment: `.css('top')` returns `145px`. `.css('left')` returns `150px`. If you try to add `150` to that, you'll end up with `150px150`. My edited answer should be correct, with the `parseInt`. `parseInt($(this).css("left")) + 150` will end up with `300`, and `left: 300` will not work, hence why you need to append `px`.

Answer (score 65):

As of jQuery 1.6, you can do this most easily by simply adding or subtracting from the current value. For example, to add 150px:

`$(this).css("left", "+=150")`

http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties

> As of jQuery 1.6, .css() accepts relative values similar to
>   .animate(). Relative values are a string starting with += or -= to
>   increment or decrement the current value. For example, if an element's
>   padding-left was 10px, .css( "padding-left", "+=15" ) would result in
>   a total padding-left of 25px.

Answer (score 2):

I've simplified thirtydot answer.
You can use this jQuery function for any property you want to add pixels.

```
jQuery.fn.addPixelsTo = function(property, pxls) {    
     return $(this[0]).css(property, (parseInt($(this[0]).css(property).substr(0,2))+pxls)+'px');
}
```

Example:

```
$('#element').addPixelsTo('border-top-width', 30);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var WinW=jQuery(window).width();
var lft =parseInt(WinW/2);
jQuery(".div").css("left" , (lft));
```

it will put the div in center of a page, then it will work fine....

Answer (score 1):

can try

```
$(this).css("left", function(){
return ($(this).css("left")+150);
});
```

for any complex modification as well

Answer (score 0):

`var lef=$(this).css("left")`

This line is returning a string, with which you are concatenating `150` by the `+` operator. You need to convert the `$(this).css("left")` string to number first.

A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GJgb3/) demo to prove my point.

So, you can do this in the following way -

`var lef = partInt($(this).css("left")) + 150;`

Now you will get addition instead of string concatenation.