# Increasing css values with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

How can I increase css values with jquery?

I want to increase values such as top and left, this is what i tried but does not work:

```
var left = 5;
$(.object).css("left" + 5);
```

the thing is that i need the value to be an integer rather than a string like "5px". I need 5 so that i can change it with numerical expressions.

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567114/adding-pixels-to-jquery-css-left-property

Comment: thank you yankee, this was useful

Comment: `$(object).css( "left", "+=5" );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yankee is right:

```
var left = parseInt($(object).css("left")); 

$(object).css('left', left+5);
```

Comment: How to stop increment this through jquery

Answer (score 14):

From [.css() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

> As of jQuery 1.6, .css() accepts relative values similar to .animate(). Relative values are a string starting with += or -= to increment or decrement the current value. For example, if an element's padding-left was 10px, .css( "padding-left", "+=15" ) would result in a total padding-left of 25px.

So, you can increment left with your js variable with:

```
var left = 5;
$(object).css('left', '+=' + left);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var left = 5;

$(object).css('left', left+=5);
```

Comment: That would always set the style to 10 (5 + 5), regardless of the previous value.

Comment: The sample code is so far from working, so I don't think that basing an answer on it is wise...

Comment: I tried the += method before, but it seems to interfere with other code, while yankee's suggestion of the duplicate was correct. Thank you