# top = $this.css("top") returning an object versus element value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML object:

```html
<div data-x="1" data-y="1" class="tile empty" style="top: 32px; left: 434px;"> 
   <div class="inner">1:1</div>
</div>
```

But for some reason... When I access it's `top` property in **jQuery** through the following code:

```
$tile = $('[data-x=1][data-y=1]'); 
top = parseInt( $tile.css("top") );
```

Then print it using the following:

```
console.log(top);
```

It gives me this in the browser:

> **Window {postMessage: ƒ, blur: ƒ, focus: ƒ, close: ƒ, parent: Window, …}**

I'm quite puzzled on this, I even stripped away the rest of my statement `- $img.height()` to `top` since it's being used on another element later on in the coding solution.

I would expect it to return **32px**, get parsed and output **32**;

Comment: Is the top variable defined elsewhere? I don't think parseInt would ever return the window object

Comment: As above, I converted your code to a snippet and it gave a strange error - changed the variable to `topx` and it worked fine.

Comment: I just did the same @freedomn-m and glad that this was the case. Is this a good question to stay since it would most likely get troublesome for other developers? I was porting some old code from another dev.

Comment: Found another example employing `top =` https://stackoverflow.com/a/6567136/5782416

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top) is a predefined global variable in browsers. It's read-only, so the assignment you're doing didn't work, and what you're seeing is its standard value (the top-level window).

Be sure to:

1. Give your code a local scope (don't leave your code at global scope), and
2. Declare your variables in that local scope, and
3. Use strict mode so that assigning to read-only variables is an error (rather than just not doing anything); strict mode has other useful things, like disabling [the horror of implicit globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*.

So for instance:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";
    // ...
    var $tile = $('[data-x=1][data-y=1]'); 
    var top = parseInt( $tile.css("top") );
    // ...
})();
```

Comment: Wow. I never knew about the top variable until today!

Comment: Neither @jro so glad I made this question.

Comment: @jro - There are [a *bunch*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) of them. `top`, `parent`, `opener`, `self`, `name`, `length`, ... Browser global scope is a nightmare. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `name`! You just saved a future headache... Kudos to you.

Comment: I always love to see that 2008 article coming back. It's like a reminder that pops up every year or so. Let's wait for a couple of days for someone asking what "use strict" is to link this one again :D